# Using requests to navigate through multiple pages

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping, bioinformatics

I am trying to navigate through the following webpage:

http://www.regulomedb.org/

Essentially, I enter my data in the textbox and then click submit. After submitting, I want to download the file that becomes available.

As of now,  I have:

```
data = {'data': 'rs7881236'}
resp = requests.post('http://www.regulomedb.org/results', data)
```

When I look at the content for resp, I am able to get the HTML text of the following page. However, what I need to do is download the file. I am unsure of how to navigate towards it after my submission. The tricky part is I need to submit my data through the first page. Then after reaching the second page, I need to somehow navigate to the download link, but I am unsure how to do that with an already generated response object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used 'inspect' in chrome to find that it's actually two calls. The search call gives back a sort of key with the name 'sid' that is then used to download the correct files. The following worked for me just testing the one example you give:

```
import requests
import re

query = 'rs7881236'
d_format = 'full' #optionas are 'full', 'gff', or 'bed'


query_payload = {'data': query}
r = requests.post('http://www.regulomedb.org/results', query_payload)
val = re.findall('name="sid" value="(.*?)"', r.text)

file_payload = {'format':d_format,'sid':val}
f = requests.post('http://www.regulomedb.org/download', file_payload)
print(f.text)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. I assumed I would need to open a session and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a library like [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/) or [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the values from the download form, and once you have those, you can make another POST request to http://www.regulomedb.org/download